# Why is my uploaded PDF file not opening in Box from C#?

Tags: c#, file-upload, box

In c#, i am trying to :

1. I am trying to convert a bytestream byte[] into pdf format
2. and then convert the pdf into memory stream
3. and then upload the stream into microsoft Box service.

I am using following code which is successfully uploading the memory stream but that uploaded stream is not opening there in my BOX account in pdf format. I can clearly see that a file is been uploaded but when i click that uploaded file to see the content, it says : cannot open the file.

Please help me to correct it.

```
public async Task BoxClient()
{
  var auth = new OAuthSession("ACCESS TOKEN", "REFRESH TOKEN", 3600, "bearer");

        var config = new BoxConfigBuilder("CLIENT ID", "CLIENT SECRET", new Uri("http://boxsdk")).Build();
        var client = new BoxClient(config, auth);
        var parentFolderId = 208465424309;
        var base64EncodedBytes = "T2sgdGhhbmtzLCANCkkgQU0gU0hLQUhSIEdJTEhPVFJB";
       
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64EncodedBytes);
       
       
        var pdfContentStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray, true);
           pdfContentStream.Position = 0;
       
        var fileRequest = new BoxFileRequest
        {
            Name = "CoforgeTest_Document17.pdf",
            Parent = new BoxFolderRequest { Id = parentFolderId.ToString() }
        };

        // Normal file upload
         var bFile = await client.FilesManager.UploadAsync(fileRequest, pdfContentStream);

      
    }
```

I WANT TO SUCCESSFULLY UPLOAD A STREAMED FILE WHICH OPENS AS WELL ON MY BOX ACCOUNT

Comment: true. Just to let you know, "Ok thanks,  I AM SHKAHR GILHOTRA" is just a sample base64 that I took. Actually, it is a big base64 file that I have to Stream to BOX.  So, as per you, If I convert to text and then stream the Text , then how will i have all the PDF styles, padding enabled there in BOX ?